# Xam.Plugin.Media doesn't pick photo from iOS gallery

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use Xam.Plugin.Media for my project. It works perfect in android version, but in iOS.... it opens gallery with buttonClick, but I can't pick photo, they are like non selectable. Do you have any idea about it?

Here is my codes:

```
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions { PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium });

            if (file == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            
            alert = UIAlertController.Create("Info", file.Path.ToString(), UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            PresentViewController(alert, true, null);            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            alert = UIAlertController.Create("Info", ex.ToString(), UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }
```

EDIT: I tested on real device, it works fine. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work on simulator.

Comment: Permission ok? And this package has been merged into [Essentia](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Comment: Yes I implemented permissions to info.plist. I will give feedback after trying essentials MediaPicker :)

Comment: And are you testing on ios simulator or a real device.

Comment: Testing on iOS simulator iPhone 11 (14.5). Is there any way to test on a real device?

Comment: Connect an iphone to mac and switch simulator to your device id?

Comment: Just easy like that? :D

Comment: It works on real device!!

Comment: That's good. It was easy as you've done lots config for running on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to see if it works.

```
if (CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
```

I test it on the simulator and it works fine.
[image]

**plus**:

Make sure your info.plist looks like:
[image]
If it does, try create a new sample app to test or use
Essential to see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can achieve to gallery on simulator, too. But it's not possible to pick and show it in imageView. I cannot click to images on simulator.

Comment: I edit the answer with some advice, you can try them